# Change color of pie chart sections in SpreadsheetGear

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I'm having trouble changing the colors of the pie chart sections in SpreadsheetGear. Normally, for a bar chart, I'm able to reference each section and set the interior color:

```
SpreadsheetGear.Charts.ISeries sumSeries = chart.SeriesCollection[0];
sumSeries.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = red;

SpreadsheetGear.Charts.ISeries sumSeriesTwo = chart.SeriesCollection[1];
sumSeriesTwo .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = blue;
```

With the pie chart, there is only one SeriesCollection so I'm not able to reference the other sections of the chart even though there are 5 different sections in the pie chart:

```
series = chart.SeriesCollection[0];
seriesTwo = chart.SeriesCollection[1]; // out of range
```

How can I change the color of the other sections in the pie chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slices of a pie chart are individual data points in a single series (a collection of [IPoint](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.Charts.IPoint_members.html) objects in ISeries.[Points](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.9.0/#SpreadsheetGear2023.Core%7ESpreadsheetGear.Charts.ISeries%7EPoints.html)[...]), so you would need to modify each IPoint in that first series to affect each slice's color.  Example:

```
ISeries series = chart.SeriesCollection[0];
series.Points[0].Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Red;
series.Points[1].Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Green;
series.Points[2].Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Blue;
```